# Full Text Index stuck

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

We recently upgraded our SQL Server database server.
We have a search on our website that uses a full text index to search.
I am now trying to figure out why the full text index appears to be stuck.

I started the index job 5 days ago and it still hasn't finished.
[image]

It has had those pending changes for the last 3 days and hasn't budged since.

I'm not sure what I can do to try to figure out why it's not indexing.

Comment: I have almost no experience with FTS in SQL, but [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/manage-and-monitor-full-text-search-for-a-server-instance?view=sql-server-ver16) has a bunch of good info on monitoring. As a start, what does `sys.dm_fts_index_population` say? What if you issue a `ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX on tblSearchCache START FULL POPULATION;`?

Answer (score 0):

So apparently the problem was that when the Full Text Index was set up in SQL Server 2012 one of the indexed columns had the Statistical Semantics option checked, which worked fine. However in SS2019 that doesn't seem to be allowed. I unchecked it and suddenly the population was able to finish.